# Testing Qt application in Visual Studio - Qt files giving 'cannot open source file' error when including project files in test file

Tags: qt, testing, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to write tests for a Qt application in visual studio.  I've added a new test project to the existing solution that has the project I'm wanting to test, and added a reference to said project as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2017).  When I try to run a test file, I get errors saying 'cannot open source file "x"' for a bunch of Qt and Qt generated files like QWidget and 'ui_x.h' (x is a placeholder).  I'm using Google Test, but the same issue occurs when using the 'Native Unit Test Project' option.

Image of problem

[image]

Settings.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QFileDialog>

#include "ui_Settings.h"

extern const std::string MODS_FOLDER_PATH;
extern const std::string  PROFILE_PATH;

class Settings : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Settings(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR, QString testHook = "");
    QString getModsFolderPath();

public slots:
    void browseProfilePath();
    void browseModsPath();
    void openSettingsWidget();

signals:
    void modsFolderPathChanged(const QString &newPath);
    void profilePathChanged();

private:
    Ui::Options ui;
    QString testHook;
    QString fileBrowser(QFileDialog::FileMode fileMode, const std::string  = "");
    bool changeFileSetting(QLineEdit * const settingInput, const std::string setting, const QString &fileName);
    void loadValuesFromSettings();
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "../FileOverwriteManager/Settings.h"

TEST(TestCaseName, TestName) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
  EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you must point the location of your Qt includes in the project settings? Look at "Configuration Properties/C/C++/Additional Include Directories" of the configuration dialog.

Comment: That works.  I tried it before but it gave so many errors that I thought it wasn't the right thing.  I had to include the specific directories where the .h files were, but also one directory higher because of, I guess, the way the Qt source includes files.  I haven't used visual studio much before, but it seems odd that adding a reference to the project doesn't take the external dependencies with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to edit the 'Additional Include Directories' under 'C/C++' in the test project's properties as suggested by user vahancho.  If you only include the directories where the .h files are, i.e. `C:\Qt\5.10.0\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore` for `qsettings.h`, then it complains like [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjs3i.jpg), so you have to also include one directory higher, i.e. `C:\Qt\5.10.0\msvc2017_64\include\`